# Custom Firebase email action handler w/ AngularFire

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication

I have built a project using AngularJS and AngularFire. I want to use the AngularFire authentication with AngularJS to handle the account management actions.

How can I use the AngularJS router to create an email action handler?

My initial thought is to do this:

```
    $routeProvider
    .when('/accountmgmt/:mode/:oobCode',{
        templateUrl: 'views/accountmgmt.html',
        controller: 'AccountMgmtCtrl'
      })
```

Then I would use $routeParams to get the values from the url and complete the action but is this correct? 
The example on the firebase documentation shows a url with this pattern:

```
 https://example.com/acctmgmt?mode=<action>&oobCode=<code>
```

Should I my route look more like this?

```
.when('/accountmgmt?mode=/:mode/&oobCode=/:oobCode', {
    templateUrl: 'views/accountmgmt.html',
    controller: 'AccountMgmtCtrl'
 })
```